# Why does this if statement require brackets?

Tags: c, if-statement

Usually, if I follow an `if` statement with a single statement, I won't need brackets.  For example:

```
if (condition) statement1; statement2;
```

`statement2` will run in any case.  But that doesn't happen here:

```
for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    if (size % 2) if (j % 2) *(minmat + j) *= -1.0;        
    else {
        …
    }
}
```

The `else` statement is supposed to associate with the first `if` statement, but it in fact associates with the second.  To correct it, I have to do this:

```
for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    if (size % 2) { if (j % 2) *(minmat + j) *= -1.0; }
    else {
        …
    }
}
```

But why does that happen, when in the first case it's “implied” that the second `if` statement is inside brackets?

Comment: C11 draft standard, section 6.8.4.1§3: `An else is associated with the lexically nearest preceding if that is allowed by the
syntax.`

Comment: else isn't associated with the first if only because your indentation suggests it.

Comment: Not a fan of MISRA-C but MISRA-C always requires `{}` for `if` statements (so even if there is a single statement inside).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An else statement will associate with the most recent if. You could also correct it like this:

```
for(j=0; j<size; j++{
    if(size%2) if(j%2) *(minmat+j) *= -1.0; else;        
    else {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This ambiguity is known as the [*dangling else*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.  Regardless of what you might find intuitive, the language designers have made the decision that the `else` be associated with the closest matching `if`.  If I think about it, I find this decision quite natural but that's debatable.  What is not debatable is that a decision had to be made and that there is no way it can be changed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you think "implied" brackets exist, or would apply here. Properly indented, you have written:

```
for(j=0; j<size; j++{
  if(size%2) 
    if(j%2) 
      *(minmat+j) *= -1.0;        
    else {
    }
}
```

An `else` is going to attach to the lexically-nearest `if`.

Answer (score 1):

From the C99 Standard:

> **6.8.4.1 The if statement**
>
> ...
>
> 3 An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is allowed by the syntax.

Hence,

```
if(size%2) if(j%2) *(minmat+j) *= -1.0;        
else {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(size%2)
{
   if(j%2) *(minmat+j) *= -1.0;        
   else {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if(size%2)
{
   if(j%2) {
      *(minmat+j) *= -1.0;
   }
   else {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`else` is an operator that is stickier to the `if` than an `if` to another `if`. Therefore it "sticks" to the closest if. It's just like multiplication goes before addition.

That's a rule that makes sense, because otherwise nested ifs without brackets would become problematically.